# How to zoom in to the location of the marker in kml

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I am using kml file to display the location on google map. i want to zoom in to that marker location while click the marker. Here is my kml layer code ,

```
 function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(11.024747, 76.898037),
      zoom: 2,
      mapTypeId: 'terrain'
    });

    var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(src, {
      suppressInfoWindows: true,
      preserveViewport: false,
      map: map
    });



    kmlLayer.addListener('click', function(event) {
      var content = event.featureData.infoWindowHtml;
      var testimonial = document.getElementById('capture');
      testimonial.innerHTML = content;
     });
  }
```

Please Help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can zoom to clicked latLng using `event.latLng` and manually setting a zoom level.

```
  kmlLayer.addListener('click', function(event) {

     map.setCenter(event.latLng);
     map.setZoom(20)

     var content = event.featureData.infoWindowHtml;
     var testimonial = document.getElementById('capture');
     testimonial.innerHTML = content;
  });
```

Please find this fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/Rohith_KP/mcwzh4an/1/

Comment: It is working. thanks for your support . i have another doubt . how to make a simple popup window to display the information of the place while mouse move into that particular marker ?

Comment: @Nisanth you can use [infoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows) to show that popup.

Comment: Also see [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml-features), If you want to show in a different place

Comment: what is the differents ?  i can't find any difference

Comment: One is google map infoWindow.. other is just a div outside the map. you can go with infoWindow. Ignore my second comment, ok?

Comment: ya sure . also i am trying the tooltip while mouse move into the marker. but it is not working. any idea ?

Comment: @Nisanth I am afraid that there is no mouseover event for KML layer. Let me check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142567/discussion-between-nisanth-and-ninja).